# Grid distribution problem during zooming of a custom graph using C#

Tags: c#, math, graph, grid, zooming

The main problem is the graph I work with is not a standard control from Visual Studio, it's a custom one. Not all the functions were designed and no documentation was provided. Right now I kinda understand how it works but I believe I'm stuck with a math problem here.

**Description:**
We have a graph with *n* curves where *0 < n <= 8*. Each curve has its own scale, so the values of X and Y axis vary.
[The sample of the curves the graph normally displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUfhG.png)

**Input:**
*TotalYLength, TotalValue, DivisionValue*.

Where:
*TotalYLength* is a difference between the bottom and the top sides of the displayed area (I believe).

*TotalValue* is a length of the current curve’s Y axis.

*DivisionValue* is a step of the grid (Default value is hard coded as 200, but can be changed).

There is also a *StartValue*, which is the first Y point of the curve but it hasn’t been used in the formula below.

*Existing solution:*

```
float newDivitionPixels = (float) ((totalYLength * _divisionValue) / TotalValue);
```

For example: 343 * 200 / 1000 = 68.6

After one zoom out: 343 * 200 / 2000 = 34.3

After two zooms out: 343 * 200 / 4000 = 17.15

It scales the graph along with the grid values: the more we zoom out – the more grids we get on the screen.

**Issue:**
The number of zooms out is unlimited, which is fine, but the grids keep being added, making this unreadable output and stopping the application when there are too many of them.

[The unreadable values after several zooms out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYcmT.png)

**Problem:** 
Find a formula which will adjust the scaling to each particular curve with the limited increase of the grid lines on the left or without changing their number at all.

I’ve tried to assign number 45 to a newDivitionPixels variable (I found this number experimentally. It gives out exactly eleven grid values). 
And also logarithms such as:

```
        TotalYLength * Math.Log(TotalYLength);

        (TotalYLength * Math.Log(TotalYLength)) / TotalValue;

        Math.Log(45, TotalYLength);

        (totalYLength / Math.Log(TotalValue));
```

And so on.
The last one has even solved the problem with the grids, but gave the wrong scaling values out. I believe I simply need an accurate mathematical formula which will display both the correct values and a limited number of grids. But I assume there might be an algorithmic solution I can't see. Will be grateful for any working suggestions since I've already spent weeks on discovering and experimenting with this part.
Here is the code of the method which draws the grid lines.

```
public void DrawAxis(Graphics graphics, Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        PointF pt1 = new PointF(XGap, YGap1);
        PointF pt2 = new PointF(XGap, rectangle.Height - YGap1);
        graphics.DrawLine(Pen, pt1, pt2); //Draws a vertical line across the Y-axis grids
        log.Debug("Draw a line from pt1 {0} to pt2 {1}", pt1.Y.ToString(), pt2.Y);

        float totalYLength = pt2.Y - pt1.Y;
        if (totalYLength < 0)
        {
            totalYLength = totalYLength * -1;
        }

        float newDivitionPixels = (float) ((totalYLength * _divisionValue) / TotalValue);
        _divisionDst = newDivitionPixels;
        if (_selected)
        {
            PointF ptOrigin = pt2;
            float ptFirstDivY = pt2.Y - ((float)((newDivitionPixels * (StartValue - Origin)) / _divisionValue));
            PointF ptFisrtDiv = ptOrigin;
            ptFisrtDiv.Y = ptFirstDivY;

            // Draw first division
            PointF ptFisrtDiv1 = ptFisrtDiv;
            ptFisrtDiv1.X = ptFisrtDiv1.X - 6;
            graphics.DrawLine(Pen, ptFisrtDiv1, ptFisrtDiv);
            log.Debug("Draw a line from ptFisrtDiv1 {0} to ptFisrtDiv {1}", ptFisrtDiv1, ptFisrtDiv);

            // Draw grid lines
            float[] dashValues = { 3, 1 };
            Pen grayPen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1);
            grayPen.DashPattern = dashValues;

            int tempX = (int)(ptFisrtDiv.X + _graphControl.UIControl.Width - _graphControl.XAxis.XGap1 - 20);
            PointF ptTop = new PointF(tempX, ptFisrtDiv.Y);
            graphics.DrawLine(grayPen, ptFisrtDiv, ptTop); //Draws longer lines for the enumerated grids
            log.Debug("Draw a line from ptFisrtDiv {0} to ptTop {1}", ptFisrtDiv, ptTop);
            //
            {
                // Draws divisions in -ve side
                PointF divPt1 = ptFisrtDiv1;
                PointF divPt2 = ptFisrtDiv;
                divPt1.X = divPt1.X + 4;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) 
                {
                    divPt1.Y = divPt1.Y + newDivitionPixels / 5;
                    divPt2.Y = divPt2.Y + newDivitionPixels / 5;
                    if (divPt2.Y > ptOrigin.Y)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    graphics.DrawLine(Pen, divPt2, divPt1); //Draws four shorter lines for the grids between two numbers
                    log.Debug("Draw a line from divPt2 {0} to divPt1 {1}", divPt2, divPt1);
                }

                // Draws divisions in +ve side
                PointF tpPt1 = ptFisrtDiv1;
                tpPt1.X = tpPt1.X + 4;
                PointF tpPt2 = ptFisrtDiv;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    tpPt1.Y = tpPt1.Y - newDivitionPixels / 5;
                    tpPt2.Y = tpPt2.Y - newDivitionPixels / 5;
                    if (tpPt1.Y < pt1.Y)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    graphics.DrawLine(Pen, tpPt1, tpPt2);
                    log.Debug("Draw a line from tpPt1 {0} to tpPt2 {1}", tpPt1, tpPt2);
                }

                PointF ptToDrawStr = ptFisrtDiv1;
                ptToDrawStr.X = ptToDrawStr.X - 40;
                string strToDraw = StartValue.ToString();
                strToDraw = GetTrimmedStr(strToDraw);
                graphics.DrawString(strToDraw, _graphControl.UIControl.Font, Pen.Brush, ptToDrawStr);
                log.Debug("Draw a string {0} at ptToDrawStr.Y {1}", strToDraw, ptToDrawStr);
            }
            {
                PointF divPt1 = ptFisrtDiv1;
                PointF divPt2 = ptFisrtDiv;
                double yAxisDivisionValue = StartValue;
                while (true)
                {
                    divPt2.Y = divPt2.Y - newDivitionPixels;
                    divPt1.Y = divPt1.Y - newDivitionPixels;
                    if (divPt1.Y < pt1.Y)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    yAxisDivisionValue = yAxisDivisionValue + _divisionValue;

                    graphics.DrawLine(Pen, divPt2, divPt1);
                    log.Debug("Draw a line from divPt2 {0} to divPt1 {1}", divPt2, divPt1);

                    // Draw grid lines
                    tempX = (int)(divPt2.X + _graphControl.UIControl.Width - _graphControl.XAxis.XGap1 - 20);
                    ptTop = new PointF(tempX, divPt2.Y);
                    graphics.DrawLine(grayPen, divPt2, ptTop);
                    log.Debug("Draw a line from divPt2 {0} to ptTop {1}", divPt2, ptTop);

                    // Draw small divisions
                    PointF tpPt1 = divPt1;
                    tpPt1.X = tpPt1.X + 4;
                    PointF tpPt2 = divPt2;

                    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                    {
                        tpPt1.Y = tpPt1.Y - newDivitionPixels / 5;
                        tpPt2.Y = tpPt2.Y - newDivitionPixels / 5;
                        if (tpPt1.Y < pt1.Y)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        graphics.DrawLine(Pen, tpPt1, tpPt2);
                        log.Debug("Draw a line from tpPt1 {0} to tpPt2 {1}", tpPt1, tpPt2);
                    }

                    PointF ptToDrawStr = divPt1;
                    ptToDrawStr.X = ptToDrawStr.X - 40;
                    string strTemp = yAxisDivisionValue.ToString();
                    strTemp = GetTrimmedStr(strTemp);
                    graphics.DrawString(strTemp, _graphControl.UIControl.Font, Pen.Brush, ptToDrawStr);
                    log.Debug("Draw a string {0} at ptToDrawStr {1}", strTemp, ptToDrawStr);
                }
            }

            PointF ptDesc = new PointF();
            ptDesc.X = 20;
            ptDesc.Y = _graphControl.UIControl.Height / 3;
            System.Drawing.StringFormat drawFormat = new System.Drawing.StringFormat();
            drawFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical | StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap;
            graphics.DrawString(AxisDescription, _graphControl.UIControl.Font, Pen.Brush, ptDesc, drawFormat);
        }

    }
```

*P.S. X-axis doesn't have this issue but it's formula doesn't match with this method.*

Comment: It sounds like you want to solve the fairly common problem of automatic scaling of graph axes, the same as what happens when you resize an Excel graph or the zoom on a map app and the distance scale changes. Is that right? Perhaps remove all the stuff about the custom control and programming language and code because it makes the question very specific and a lot of work to understand. Also, including the pictures directly instead of linking will help future readers after they're gone.

Comment: It does sound right to me, just a scaling problem. And I thought it's better to provide as much information as possible on this site and show the work I've done before I came here. That's funny, but I don't have enough reputation to post pictures here.